# Error in code of bisection method

Tags: matlab

I used a code for bisection method, which supposed to be working, unfortunately it´s not and I do not know what is the problem. This code also includes user defined precision and a counter for number of iterations. The error I´m getting is for the last line in the code: Undefined function or variable 'c'.

```
a=-5;
b=0;
tol = input('What precision would you like? ','s')
fa=a^3-20+exp(a);
fb=b^3-20+exp(b);
counter=1
while abs(b-a) > tol
  c=(a+b)/2;
  fx = c*c-2;
  if fa*fc<0
      b=c;
      fb=fc;
  elseif fb*fc<0
      a=c;
      fa=fc;
  else
      break
  end
  fprintf('Just finished iteration #%d\n', counter);
  counter=counter+1;
end
x=c;
```

Comment: `input` with the parameter 's' returns a string of `char` so `tol` is a string, you have either to remove 's' or to conver the `tol` to a num (`str2num`). If you try debugging your code, most prbably the `while` loop is not executed, therefore the varaible `c` is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are loading the `input` as a string (with the `s` argument), the `tol` variable will be a character array.  For example, entering `1E-10` for the current script will define `tol` as a character array, and the first evaluation of the expression in the `while` construct will be equivalent to

```
>> abs(0 - -5) > '1E-10'
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0
```

So the `while` loop is completely skipped.

So either remove `s` from the `input` call, or wrap the `input` call in a `str2double`.